# Is compression used in RDS SQLServer database

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, aws, compression

I have few Clarification regarding AWS RDS SQL Server.

Do we have any compression technique to compress the data loaded into RDS SQL server?
Is there any option or parameter to compress the data and load into RDS SQL server?

Answer (score 2):

After you have loaded the data into a table, and as long as you have signed up for a 2016 Standard Edition or above, you can use the [Data Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-2017) that is included within Sql Server:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    ... -- whatever columns you need.
)
WITH 
(
    DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE
);
```

You can also create compressed indexes in a similar fashion:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_t1 ON t1(...) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE);
```

For more information, check out the documentation for [Enabling Compression on a a Table or Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/enable-compression-on-a-table-or-index?view=sql-server-2017).